# 'C:\Users\HP' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python, installation, jupyter-notebook, kernel, vpython

I tried installing
`pip install vpython`
[Getting error like restart kernel and 'C:\Users\HP' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4COy.png)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a space in your user name in windows, and the program isn't using quoted paths. I suggest you try installing the package in a [virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html).

*(If you're using jupyter notebook / any other notebook there should be virtual environment setup in it. Or there should be a plugin for it.)*

You can also use [pipx](https://github.com/pypa/pipx) which is like pip inside virtual environment.

```
pip3 install pipx
```

If you want to fix this permanently i suggest you reinstall python in a custom path. I suggest `C:\Python3` but its upto you :)

I hope that helped :)

Answer (score -1):

You have missed to write **PHP** instead You have written **hp**
change ## hp##
to ## php##